# Tensor to vector notation

Tags: vectors, tensor-calculus, notation

I have the expression
$$ \partial_{k} \left( a^{-1} b^{2} \eta^{j k} \partial_{j} G \right) = a \vec{\nabla} . \left( a^{-2} b^{2} \vec{\nabla} G \right) $$

Is the transition from tensor to vector notation well written? I understand that but $$\eta^{j k} \partial_{j} G = \vec{\nabla} G$$ but I don't see how to include the $a$ and $a^{-2}$. Could you guide me? Maybe it's a repeated question but I didn't find an answer or maybe it's simpler than I think and I'm getting complicated.

Comment: This looks like [the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#In_curvilinear_coordinates) $\nabla_kV^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_k\left(\sqrt{|g|}V^k\right)$ for $|g|=a^2,\,V^k=a^{-1}b^2\partial^kG$.

Comment: no, it can't be right. on the right-hand side you have a gradient of a gradient (a tensor of order = order(G)+2) while you have a scalar on the left-hand side. Maybe only a typo, but you need a dot product after the first nabla in the abstract notation

Comment: @basics You're right. I already corrected it, sorry

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?